# Open connection to SQLite secured database with navicat

Tags: c#, sqlite, navicat

I have a SQLite database and i managed to set a password from c#.

```
_connection.ChangePassword("test");
```

and then i connect like:

```
_connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString +
                                            "example.db;Version=3;Max Pool Size=2;Password=test;");
```

My problem now is that i want to have a GUI management tool to manage the database file. I use navicat for SQLite but i cant connect to the secured database file.

The error i am facing is "26 - file is encrypted or is not a database"

Is there another management program or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

System.Data.Sqlite uses a non standard encryption files encrypted by it are only read by system.data.sqlite